# How to make tornado execute concurrent code?

Tags: python, concurrency, tornado

I'm trying to write a simple workload generator for a Tornado server, here's its simplified version:

```
class EventsLoader(object):

    generate_num_requests = 1000
    generate_concurrency = 32
    server_port = 8001

    def __init__(self, conf_file):
        self.parse_config(conf_file)
        self.client = AsyncHTTPClient()

    def generate(self):
        IOLoop.current().run_sync(self.generate_work)

    @gen.coroutine
    def generate_work(self):
        self.queue = queues.Queue()
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.fetch_requests)
        for i in range(self.generate_concurrency):
            yield self.generate_requests(i)
        print 'before join queue size: %s' % self.queue.qsize()
        yield self.queue.join()

    @gen.coroutine
    def generate_requests(self, i):
        load = self.generate_num_requests / self.generate_concurrency
        for j in range(load):
            request = self.generate_request(i * 1000 + j)
            self.queue.put(request)

    @gen.coroutine
    def fetch_requests(self):
        while True:
            try:
                request = yield self.queue.get()
                yield self.client.fetch(request)
            except Exception as e:
                print 'failed fetching: %s: %s' % (request.body, e)
            finally:
                print 'fetched: %s' % json.loads(request.body)['seq']
                self.queue.task_done()

    def generate_request(self, seq):
        event = {
            'seq': seq,
            # ... more fields here ...
        }
        return HTTPRequest(
            'http://localhost:%s/events' % self.server_port,
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(event),
        )
```

What I see happen is that all messages `fetched: xxxx` appear in sequential order, which is absolutely improbable, if the generator was indeed working concurrently.

How do I make it run concurrently? There must be something huge missing in my understanding of what I/O loop is for, and what `@gen.coroutine` does.  I.e. regardless of my `generate_concurrency` setting, the performance is unchanged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async function call with Tornado Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139848/async-function-call-with-tornado-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you're generating the requests, you've only got on task fetching them. It's the fetching, not the generating, that you need to parallelize:

```
for i in range(self.fetch_concurrency):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.fetch_requests)
```

This will give you multiple `fetch_requests` workers that can pull work from the shared queue.

Also, the generation part of this code isn't running in parallel either. Instead of

```
   for i in range(self.generate_concurrency):
        yield self.generate_requests(i)
```

which waits for one `generate_requests` call to finish before starting the next, you can run them in parallel with

```
yield [self.generate_requests(i) for i in range(self.generate_concurrency)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed worked, however, if you don't mind, can you explain why `yield` in a loop for `generate_requests` didn't work? Shouldn't yielding control back to tornado start next `generate_request` without waiting for the previous to complete? Also, with your change applied, the `i`s are generated sequentially, but `j`s are generated in "random" (expected) order.

Comment: Actually, let me guess. `generate_requests` doesn't do any I/O, and it doesn't matter if it yields control or not, Tornado isn't able to take advantage of that? Or maybe Tornado has very large interval between at which it looks at potential candidates between all coroutines scheduled for execution, so `generate_requests` simply finishes before Tornado even considers to suspend it.

Comment: Yes, Tornado is based on cooperative multitasking and `generate_requests` can only be parallelized if it contains `yield` expressions that wait on I/O. But even if it did, the original `generate_requests` loop with a `yield` on each iteration was instructing Tornado to wait for each one to finish before moving on to the next one.